# Flutter webView not finish the loadingbar

Tags: flutter, webview

Hi I am struggling with the Flutter webView implementation in my app. It just does not stop circularProgressIndicator.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedUrl;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =  Completer<WebViewController>();
  MyWebView({
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });
  bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new WebView(
            initialUrl: selectedUrl,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
                isLoading = false;
            },
          ),
          isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see from my code...the isLoading value is not changed to false . since it is a statelesswidget i can not use setState() here. I am calling this webView from another page by:

```
return Scaffold(body: new MyWebView( selectedUrl:"https://www.google.com"),);
```

the selectedUrl is a dynamic value i pass from different page

Comment: Convert `MyWebView` to stateful widget or you can use state management to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `StatefulBuilder`

code snippet

```
 return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(

...     

        onPageFinished: (finish) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
          },
```

working demo

[image]

**Edit Revised Full Code use IndexedStack**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedUrl;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  MyWebView({
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });
  //bool isLoading = true;
  num _stackToView = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _stackToView,
          children: <Widget>[
            new WebView(
              initialUrl: selectedUrl,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onPageFinished: (finish) {
                print("onPageFinished");
                setState(() {
                  _stackToView = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new MyWebView(selectedUrl: "https://flutter.dev/"),
    );
  }
}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedUrl;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  MyWebView({
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });
  bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new WebView(
              initialUrl: selectedUrl,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onPageFinished: (finish) {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            isLoading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new MyWebView(selectedUrl: "https://flutter.dev/"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi.. i m having another issue with the webview... in the website(inside webview) the loader appears after sometimes(frequently)

Comment: You can see my updated revised full code use IndexedStack